# "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Ive encounter an error 
Input string was not in a correct format .

here's the code:

```
int id = (columnNames.Length > 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(columnNames[0]) : 0;
```

Comment: So, what do you want us to do about it? Your input string is not in the correct format! It's not an integer. What's in there?

Comment: the value in columnNames[0] is an integer .

Comment: @user3363284 then why do you want to convert it again

Comment: Are you sure that columnNames[0] is a string that can be interpreted as an integer? Try to set a breakpoint on that line and check what is the value in columnNames[0]

Comment: No, you think that it _should be_ an integer, but clearly, sometimes it is not. Does it contain spaces or commas, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int id = (columnNames.Length > 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(columnNames[0].ToString()) : 0;
```

If columnNames[0] is int? then

```
int id = (columnNames.Length > 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(columnNames[0] ?? 0) : 0;
```

Comment: So columnNames[0] requires a conversion to a string. But if it is not a string then what is it? an int? somewhere something is not right....

Comment: Possible, but I am wondering why you should name an array if int?  `columnNames`. Oh well wait for a response from the poster...